# unreal engine 5 Не могу сбилдить проект

Tags: unreal-engine, unrealscript, unreal-engine-5

При попытке упаковать проект у меня возникает следующая ошибка (см скрин).
Visual studio не устонавливается (Это было во многих ответах на похожий вопрос)
Прокет билдится без проблем и запускается в двежке так же без проблем.

Unreal engine 5.0.1
Путь к проекты менял на полностью латинский, не помогло[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установка Visual Studio 2022 решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Не могу поставить, живу в РФ, для нас заблокировали приложения Microsoft

Comment: Живу в РФ, с такой проблемой не сталкивался :(

Comment: возможный аналог VS для ue 5 -> Rider,

Comment: Спасибо большое Попробую